# Replace the ' character in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean up a text file that has a number of extra ' characters in it.

All the normal methods I've tried won't see the ' as anything but the start of a string, for example 
     Where-Object ' {S_ -match ...}

I've tried using REGEX which has the same issue.

My experience with PowerShell is limited so please excuse me if there is a DOH! moment coming my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine...

```
"isn't 'this' a`r`nmulti-line`r`nstring`r`n'full' of single quotes like these '''?" -replace "'",''
```

The `-replace "'",''` section replaces any single quotes with nothing, using regex (although this is a very simple regex!)